# UNIQUE constraint failed username error while changing user details

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have custom user model by extending `AbstractUser` class. I want to make form to change user's fullname and website field.
My user:

```
class Hacker(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.name:
            return self.name
        else:
            return self.username
```

And forms.py:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Edit profile form
    """
    name = forms.CharField(label=_("Name"),
                           widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Name')}))
    description = forms.CharField(label=_("Description,Position"), required=False,
                                  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Description, Position')}))
    website = forms.URLField(label=_("Website"), required=False,
                             widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Website URL')}))

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'website']
```

In page I use {{ field }} to add inputs and in POST part of views:

```
form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=True)
        ...
```

But `form.save` gives `UNIQUE constraint failed: common_hacker.username` error. What can be problem here?

Comment: Ref https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user you are extending django's standard user model (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) which means your users are required to have unique usernames. Are you trying to use/change the username field at all?

Comment: @TomDalton No, that form do not modify username or password fields. There is username field due to extending `AbstractUser` class. There is no problem in Adding, modifying users in admin and rest-api (django rest framework). But I don't know why it give such an error in this form. I was thinking that it tries to create new user, but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `instance=request.user` when creating form fixed problem:

`form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)`